# Dropdown animado com jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site, e em seu cabeçalho deve conter um Dropdown que aparece ao dar um hover no link do cabeçalho, de preferência com a animação dele surgindo, porém ele está com um bug que quando você vai pro dropdown ele tenta se esconder, e então aparece novamente. Com CSS puro consegui faze-lo sem a animação de slide, mas gostaria de dar uma estilizada nele, já tentei com o CSS puro com transition e as animações do @webkit.

Eis o código abaixo:

**HTML:**

```
<li id="showDropdown" <?=$page=='areas.php' ? 'class="active"' : '';?>>
                <a class="areas" href="Javascript:void(0);">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-areas">
                    <? while($row_rsAreas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsArea)) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="area.php?id=<?=$row_rsAreas['area_id'];?>"><?=$row_rsAreas['area_titulo'];?></a>
                        </li>
                    <? } ?>
                </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-areas {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(54, 52, 53, 0.9);
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-areas li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-areas li a {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--corFont);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showDropdown').hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-areas').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cara acho que vc vai ter que colocar um setTimeout() ai para evitar que a animação recomece antes de terminar ou se interrompa caso o usuário remova ou entre e saia rápido do menu algo assim... eu não manjo de jQuery então não consegui te ajudar muito nessa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `.hover` dispara 2 eventos: `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`. Ao usar apenas 1 função no método, você executa o mesmo código (`.slideToggle()`) 2 vezes, o que causa bug, porque irá enfileirar a animação onde uma irá atropelar a outra.

Em vez disso, trate os eventos dentro do `.hover` de forma separada, cada um com a sua função:

```
$('#showDropdown').hover(
   function(){
      // AQUI TRATA O MOUSEENTER
   },
   function(){
      // AQUI TRATA O MOUSELEAVE
   }
);
```

Em vez de usar `.slideToggle()`, use `.slideDown()` no `mouseenter` e `.slideUp()` no `mouseleave`.

E para evitar ainda mais bugs, coloque ainda um `if` na primeira função verificando se o elemento está invisível antes de aplicar a animação que mostra o elemento.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#showDropdown').hover(
      function() {
         if(!$('.dropdown-areas').is(":visible"))
         $('.dropdown-areas').slideDown(1000);
      },
      function() {
         $('.dropdown-areas').slideUp(1000);
      }
   );
});
```

```css
.dropdown-areas {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(54, 52, 53, 0.9);
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-areas li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-areas li a {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--corFont);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="showDropdown" <?=$page=='areas.php' ? 'class="active"' : '';?>>
    <a class="areas" href="Javascript:void(0);">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-areas">
        <? while($row_rsAreas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsArea)) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="area.php?id=<?=$row_rsAreas['area_id'];?>"><?=$row_rsAreas['area_titulo'];?></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Você também pode usar o método [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) em cada função antes de aplicar o slide. Isso dispensa o uso do `if` na primeira função:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#showDropdown').hover(
      function() {
         $('.dropdown-areas').stop().slideDown(1000);
      },
      function() {
         $('.dropdown-areas').stop().slideUp(1000);
      }
   );
});
```

```css
.dropdown-areas {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(54, 52, 53, 0.9);
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-areas li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-areas li a {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--corFont);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="showDropdown" <?=$page=='areas.php' ? 'class="active"' : '';?>>
    <a class="areas" href="Javascript:void(0);">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-areas">
        <? while($row_rsAreas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsArea)) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="area.php?id=<?=$row_rsAreas['area_id'];?>"><?=$row_rsAreas['area_titulo'];?></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

### Funcionamento em dispositivos mobile (touch screen)

Como esses dispositivos não detectam `mouseenter`, basta acrescentar um evento `.click` no elemento, desta vez com `.slideToggle()`:

```
$('#showDropdown').click(function(){
   $('.dropdown-areas').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Comment: Outro ponto interessante seria limpar a fila de animação daquele elemento com o método [`jQuery.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), senão as animações poderiam ocorrem mesmo depois do usuário já ter parado de interagir. Ficaria `$('.dropdown-areas').stop().slideDown(600);` e não precisaria do `is.(':visible')` (e o mesmo no slideUp)

Comment: @fernandosavio obg pela dica. Vou acrescentar na resposta.

Comment: Acabei criando uma resposta para complementar a sua (pois na minha só abordo o uso do stop). :D

Comment: Beleza aqui funcionou, apenas a versão mobile desta mesma animação meio que parou de funcionar, devo criar uma igual, mas para a função click() resolveria isso?

Comment: Mobile não tem `mouseenter` e `mouseleave` por motivos óbvios :D
Teria que achar outro evento melhor, talvez `touch`.

Comment: @aleque_b Adicionado na resposta. Abs!

Comment: E está funcionando perfeitamente, um obrigado e um abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método [`jQuery.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) para cancelar a animação que já está acontecendo antes de recomeçar a nova animação.

Sem o `stop`, se o usuário fizer o `hover` várias vezes seguidas rapidamente, a animação continuará mesmo depois de o usuário deixar de interagir com o *dropdown*.

Faça o teste no código abaixo:

```js
let dropdownAreas = $('.dropdown-areas');

$('#showDropdown').hover(
    function() {
       dropdownAreas.slideDown(500);
    },
    function() {
       dropdownAreas.slideUp(500);
    }
 );
```

```css
.dropdown-areas {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(54, 52, 53, 0.9);
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-areas li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-areas li a {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--corFont);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="showDropdown">
    <a class="areas" href="Javascript:void(0);">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-areas">
            <li><a href="area.php?id=1">Área 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="area.php?id=2">Área 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="area.php?id=3">Área 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Com o `stop`, cada animação cancela a animação anterior. Veja no snippet abaixo:

```js
let dropdownAreas = $('.dropdown-areas');

$('#showDropdown').hover(
    function() {
       dropdownAreas.stop().slideDown(500);
    },
    function() {
       dropdownAreas.stop().slideUp(500);
    }
 );
```

```css
.dropdown-areas {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(54, 52, 53, 0.9);
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-areas li {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-areas li a {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--corFont);
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="showDropdown">
    <a class="areas" href="Javascript:void(0);">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-areas">
            <li><a href="area.php?id=1">Área 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="area.php?id=2">Área 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="area.php?id=3">Área 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```